# Allow access to GCP resource to any member of our Workspace instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We have a Google Workspace instance. How do we allow access to a resource (such as a bucket or App Engine) to *any* authenticated user part of our Google Workspace instance and not to anyone else?

Comment: Use the **domain** member type in IAM. https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#g-suite-domain e.g. **"domain:example.com"**

Comment: Please expand on this: Is `domain:example.com` an IAM principal? A user account? Do I need to create it? If so, how?

Comment: `example.com` is your Google Workplace domain, e.g. `someone@mydomain.com`. Google supports domains similar to how groups are supported. `domain:` is a prefix that means everyone in your domain.

Answer (score 1):

The Workspace Super Admin can [control who has access](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9197205?hl=en) to the Google Cloud Platform service from the Workspace Admin console.

In addition to @JohnHanley's suggestion, it is also recommended to use [Google groups in Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/groups-in-cloud-console) for IAM permissions/roles, instead of granting IAM roles to individual users.

You would also need the correct permissions from the Google Workspace Admin.

> To create, view, edit, and delete groups, in the Google Cloud console or elsewhere, you need the appropriate group permissions. These permissions are managed by Google Workspace, not IAM.

And then assign the [appropriate roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles) to the created group